# How to "De-initialize" ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In the first screenshot, `LatestPost` is set as `Is Initial View Controller`. When I press `Camera` tab, it launches the `.Camera` for `UIImagePickerController`. However when I hit "Cancel", it dismisses the current `ViewController`, and my tab bar goes missing as shown on the second screenshot.

The second screenshot is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`.

[image]

[image]

I quite certain that has got to do with dismissing my `ViewController`. The question here is how do I "de-initialized" my `ViewController`?

My codes as follow:

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

EDIT: Added Storyboard screenshot as requested.

[image]

Comment: do you use storyboard? if yes please provide screenshot of your storyboard

Comment: @DoanCuong Added storyboard screenshot. The above Navigation controller belongs to `Latest Posts`, while the below is `Camera`.

Comment: well, everything are looking fine, could you share the source code?

Comment: U meant that my `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` is correct? Is there a way to "de-initialized" instead?